# how can I transfer files from raspberry pi 3 to windows and android via WiFi hotspot?

Tags: raspbian, python, wifi, wireless, wifi-direct

I want to transfer different types of files from the Raspbian OS to the windows and android through a WiFi hotspot that we created already,without a internet connection we need transfer the files?please tell me the complete steps....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both computers are attached to the same wireless hotspot, then they should be able to contact one another directly via IP address. This is the same as on a normal internet connected LAN -- hence you can also use the same kind of software to transport the files.  Using SMB/CIFS is popular with Windows users, implemented by [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) on the linux side.  To that end you will find many questions tagged [samba](/questions/tagged/samba) here and [an order of magnitude more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samba) on our big sibling site *Unix & Linux*.  Note that Raspbian is essentially a normal GNU/Linux OS distro with some cosmetic and configuration tweaks.

You are not bound to use SMB/CIFS, of course.  I believe [there is some Windows side software around](http://deneb.homedns.org/things/?p=354) to mount [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) shares, which is more popular with linux users.  You can also use normal FTP, a web server, etc. etc.

WRT Android there look to be both Samba and SSHFS *clients* available.

Answer (score -1):

WinSCP for windows. For Android if you can access the root just use scp. If not try to find scp Android apps.

Comment: This is not very helpful. Ask yourself this if you were the OP would you know what WinSCP is? Where do I get it? What if he is on a Mac? How do I use it if i get it installed? Are there any prerequisites?

Comment: Per Steve's comment above, while this does at least take a stab at answering the question, it's not a complete answer. Please consider expanding it to explain what each of the parts involved is (preferably with some links to manuals or project homepages), and exactly how they would be applied to this particular problem.